# Emoticon text code

Tags: wordplay, rebus, language, emoji

I found this text on my phone.

Is there a genius out there that is able to tell me what this means?

[image: ️ ♾️️8️⃣]

Edit:

I received a similar message again:

[image: ️ א♾️️8️⃣]

Edit II:

A new message... it's all Greek to me:

[image: ‍♀️♾️‍♀️☀️✡️☀️]

Comment: This looks like **you** sent these messages on WhatsApp.

Comment: Yeah, have you worked out what it means?

Comment: Yeah, it's on the right side which means you sent it.

Comment: It's a puzzle. What does it mean?

Comment: Hm.. could you add some hints or would you like people to guess with them?

Comment: For the sceptics in comments above, suspend belief... Imagine the OP is just forwarding on the messages they received :)

Comment: Does it represent Unicode in any way?

Comment: @1357924680a They are not posted using unicode because it doesn't always come out well on desktop browsers. But they are unicode characters.

Comment: Is the [rebus] tag any important?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The top half:

> HOLE+E(*an abbreviation for the drug Ecstasy*)+BI(*‘s on*)+BULL making **HOLY BIBLE**

The bottom half is referring to:

> **GENESIS 1:1** in **HEBREW**:
>  [image]

Why?

> Here is the rebus decoded: BRA-SH*T-BRA-‘ELLO-HIM([*AB*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ab_(given_name)) *is a male name*)-ETERNAL-SHHM(*wind/blowing sound*)-V-EIGHT-HEARTS

> Speed up this [video x2](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=EYyyt7F6SD8) from 0:46 and you will see it sounds a lot like the Hebrew!

Edit 1:

> Is cluing Hebrew and the passage because of the [ALEPH symbol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph) (the passage starts with it) and since the message is now reading from **RIGHT TO LEFT** (Hebrew is read that way).

Here is what is think is going
on with edit 2:

> It is the **New Testament Matthew 1:1** which when roughly translated from the Greek passage into English: Βίβλος γενέσεως Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ υἱοῦ Δαυὶδ υἱοῦ Ἀβραάμ.

Goes

> Bible  of the genesis ‍♀️  (Genna+seas) of Jesus ♾️‍♀️ Christ (the king) son ☀️ of David ✡️ son ☀️ of Abra  ham .

Comment: I think this must be it, well done! And explains the backwards message too. Any idea on Edit II? Thought it might be either a continuation or the same passage in Greek?

Comment: For part II, I think you need to pay more attention to the rubric.

Comment: I am giving you the opportunity to get the second part right. You haven't identified the text correctly. Please be patient.

Comment: Oh I see what it is

Comment: Got it  nice puzzle btw

Answer (score -3):

It seems like some emojis are modifiers, so we need to modify the words based on what the modifiers want. Additionally, the second image has the second line reversed, so to solve it probably needs to be backwards in some way.

hole seems like it modifies the middle of a word, thus pill could either be pl, or pol. ox seems like it would 'ex' out a letter, so cow becomes ow in all likelihood; I cannot think of how else you could modify it, and also combine with pl or pol; hence, the first word is "plow".

The second line is trickier since reading the intent behind some of these is tough. However, i believe I understand the first bit. A two-piece swimsuit is missing the middle, hence the middle of the word must be dropped - however, why not use the hole emoji again? perhaps to add complexity? Regardless, if my reading is correct, this gives us, in all likelihood, 'st' and 'we'. Could also be 'pp' and 'we', but 'st' seems more likely to be used in a sentence, especially if the sentence needs to be reversed, as very few words end with 'pp' besides shorthand such as 'app'.

AB is most likely a modifier to take the first two letters - the main question is, how do you read the infinity sign? would we take 'in', or is this a trick and we're expected to read it as a lemniscate/lazy eight? this gives us the option of either 'in' or 'le'.

For this next one, I am a bit lost. A wind/blow modifier on what I can only assume is Spock. I think this means a jumble or rearrangement is necessary, but it would probably need to be in context with the rest of the sentence, as you can't do much with the current letters; it may also need to be split into two words, e.g. with 'ks' being part of one word, and 'cop' being part of another.

The final one is a bit easier to understand, eight (ate), and love. so you'd bite off a letter or two for love, leaving 'ove'/'lov', or 've'/'lo'.

To sum it up, this gives 'st' 'we' 'in'/'le' 'spock' 'ove'/'lov'. Of course, this still has to be reversed.

west is likely for the final(?) word, though nwest/niwest (newest) might be possible, and/or lwest/lewest (lowest)... depends how much warping of the words are allowed. I'll assume little to no warping for now, since 'plow' was straightforward. On the other end, I really don't like the 'v' being part of the answer, it messes things up too much with such a dearth of vowels, so I imagine the bite is 2 letters off love, giving 'lo'. this would nicely make 'look' or 'looks', taking the 'ok[s]' from our jumbled Spock, but then the remaining letters don't make anything nice. 'Lock[s]' could work instead, taking the 'ck[s]' from Spock. this leaves '[s]po', and that will fit with 'le', thus giving 'pole[s]'.

So our three words are 'west' 'pole[s]' 'lock[s]', along with 'plow' from the first line. All together, this gives us the final answer, "Plow west, pole locks" (I presume the intent is to combine 'pole' and 'locks', though I am unsure if it's trying to be pollock, pillock, or Polack).

Comment: I think this is a bot.

Comment: Should I be offended that you dislike my way of reasoning? I admit the answer is highly improbable, but if I'm on the right track then maybe someone else might find the correct solution with a different combination of letter removals. My main reasoning is the doubling up of the bikini emoji, by the way; it seems highly unlikely that any phrase would want that, twice, so I figured they had to be modifiers. If those are modifiers, then it's probable there are other modifiers, and I worked them out from there.

Comment: This answer does not look like it was written by a chatbot. A numeric or autogenerated username is characteristic of users that use a third-party sign-on feature; this website supports Google and Facebook sign-ons.